# Can limits of sequences be treated like limits of functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

In our Analysis class we learned that we can apply the following tools to determine the limits of sequences

1. Sandwich theorem
2. Ratio  test
3. Cauchy-Criteria

In the meantime we also looked into limits of series and functions. 
So I asked myself if I can apply the tools I use for functions (for example hôpital or taylor) to calculate limits of sequences?

Thanks!

Comment: What you're asking for is not even wrong.  It doesn't make sense to talk about L'hopital or taylor approximations for sequences.  However, if your sequence is given as a smooth function evaluated at integers ( eg. $s_n=\frac{n}{3n+1}$ ) then the corresponding tools for evaluating limits of functions will sometimes help you.  Even then, what you're hoping for is too general, probably.  eg. $s_n = \sin(\pi n)$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=0$ while $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(\pi x)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem:**

Let $a_{n} = f(n)$ where $f(x)$ is a real valued function. If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ = $L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = L$.

**Proof:**

Let $\epsilon$ > 0 be given. By definition of limit at infinity $\exists$ an $A \in \mathbb{R} : \forall x > A$, |$f(x) - L$| < $\epsilon$. Suppose $n > A$. Then
$$|a_{n} - L| = |f(n) - L| < \epsilon . $$

Note that as mentioned in other answers the converse of the theorem is not true!

Comment: Just to note: Callus gave a good counterexample in his comment why the other way round does not work.

Comment: The converse would be: every function can be treaded like a sequence?

Comment: Essentially. In this case the converse is precisely - If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = L$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ = $L$. And as Callus pointed out, this implication is false.

Comment: Also I have to add, I know what you mean in your question.. but it might be useful to choose more careful words. A sequence $is$ a function. Martin mentions this in his answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

General principle: sequences are functions $\Bbb N\longrightarrow\Bbb R$, so most properties of functional limits can be trivially extended to sequence limits. About the concrete cases:

1. Particular case of the general principle.
2. Ratio test is a criterion for the convergence of **series**.
3. A Cauchy sequence is convergent (beacause the completness of $\Bbb R$), but   knowing that a sequence is convergent isn't knowing the *limit*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though the Ratio test can also be applied to sequences. If the ratio is < 1 the sequence converges to 0, if it's  = 1 it's undefined, if the ratio is > 1 the sequence diverges.

Comment: @Fill, true. The problem of this use is that is mostly... useless. Can't be used to prove then $n^2\to\infty$ or $1/n\to 0$.